# GoLang conversion webm to mp3

Tags: go, mp3, webm

this is example of my code

```
package main 

import (
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/kkdai/youtube"
)

func getVideo() {
  client := youtube.Client{}
  currentVideo, videoError := client.GetVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGEJNZd1hTA")
  resp, err := client.GetStream(currentVideo, &currentVideo.Formats.Type("audio/webm")[0])
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", req.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
  w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WHATEVER_YOU_WANT.webm")
  io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/video", getVideo)

  http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

So the question is how can i convert my webm stream to mp3 and give it to the client?

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a good option to work with media.
You can try to use this using go's [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) pkg and run ffmpeg commands from there.

Some libraries that offer bindings for ffmpeg in go - [ffmpeg-go](https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go)
[goav](https://github.com/giorgisio/goav)
[gmf](https://github.com/3d0c/gmf)

Comment: Yes, but it weight too much and what if i want to do it asynchronously? As i know ffmpeg creates child process, so i can't run new process while previous is not finished

Comment: What you need is a transcoder to convert media. Most of the transcoders are +/- 10% of each other. So there is no such "light weight" solution here. And about the asynchronous behaviour, it depends on what you want to achieve here. The exact transaction between memory and media should define the handling either concurrently or in parallel. Shed some more light on behaviour you expect.